# How to disable / hide console logs in production?

Tags: javascript

I am using cordova to build my app. 
I want to hide all logs created by console.log in production app.
But I could not find any solution to disable it.

Is this really possible to hide console logs ?

I'll really appreciate any contribution.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: `console.log` is plain JS, nothing to do with Cordova or Ionic.

Comment: yes I know but I used thousands of console.log(); I am using it for debugging purpose. I don't want to remove all those so that I can re-use them in future to debug any issue. But for now I just want some way to hide all of those logs instead of removing lines manually.

Comment: I wrote my own Logger class, which allows me to set a level for debugging messages and enable/disable it. That way, I only go through my Logger layer and avoid console.log being used directly. That said, for simplicity, you could just override the console.log function with an empty function block, as described by C14L below. If the console isn't being displayed, then it's not really going to do any massive harm to leave those log statements in there. It may help you debug production problems to at least have SOME console.log statements remaining. Or remove them prior to release. Up to you.

Comment: Are you minifying your code for production? This should strip out any console.logs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just override the `log` method of the `console` object.

```
console.log = function(){}
```

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm !!

Comment: This will work until you actually need to use console.log during some important debugging - use a wrapper function that can be overridden to delegate to console.log or nowhere instead